# Cannot call font awesome from js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm calling font awesome thumb down/up with js but it's not working im using 5.6.3 version of font awesome.

JS

```
function changered() {
   document.getElementById('iconsred').style.content = "f164"; // forecode
   document.getElementById('iconsred').style.fontFamily = "Font Awesome 5 Free"; // fontfamily
}
```

in this code im already calling the thumb down but i want to change it on click and to show the filled thumb down button

HTML

```
<i id="iconsred" class="far fa-thumbs-down fa-5x right"></i>
```

i have seen someone asking the same question on stack overflow but i couldn't get my issue resolve from their answer

Comment: The best way to deal with your problem is to change css class to the corresponding one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`content` can only be used on pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` (which FontAwesome uses to show icons).

Unfortunately those pseudo elements are **not part of the DOM**, hence they cannot be accessed using Javascript.

Instead, add an event listener that changes the CSS class on click:

```js
iconsred.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle('far');
  event.target.classList.toggle('fas');
})
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i id="iconsred" class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i>
```

Comment: yes but im not using ::before and ::after right now my code is based on js so can you tell me how can i call the font from js ?

Comment: I'm saying with your approach you would **have to use `::before`** but you cannot. Instead, as I added to my answer, toggle the appropriate CSS classes.

Comment: but the problem is its changing on double click on my side

Comment: @faseeh Well that's a completely different issue. You might want to ask a new question about that. This question here is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to change an icon from js is by changing its classList.

```
document.getElementById('iconsred').classList.add('fa-icon-name-here');
```

Also

```
document.getElementById('iconsred').classList.remove('fa-old-icon-you-dont-want-anymore-here');
```